# android erasing bitmap. - Not able to save the proper bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, eraser

I am developing app i have 1 Functionality like [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handycloset.android.eraser&hl=en)
I have done this by [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132610/android-photo-background-eraser-need-help-not-erasing-bitmap-but-just-draws-bla)

Now i want to save the erased bitmap to save

Actually i have a bitmap loaded in canvas [image: The first scrren]

Now i am trying to Erase the bitmap like this [image: (added on transperent canvas]

And when user press save then only this must output [image: (save as .png)]
this is my OnDraw method

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, null);
        //  c2.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            for (PathPoints p : paths) {
                mPaint.setColor(p.getColor());
                Log.v("", "Color code : " + p.getColor());
                if (p.isTextToDraw()) {
                    canvas.drawText(p.textToDraw, p.x, p.y, mPaint);
                } else {
                    // if(isTouched)
                            c2.drawPath(p.getPath(), mPaint);

                }

            }
        }
```

And onsave Button i have done

```
Bitmap editedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawView
                        .getDrawingCache());
                editedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(editedImage, 200, 300,
                        true);
```

But this gives me only the full image(First screen shot) You can see my  [entire Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132610/android-photo-background-eraser-need-help-not-erasing-bitmap-but-just-draws-bla)